# How can I access second if statment after choosing first if statment without restarting the serial?

Tags: c, arduino, serial-port

I wrote a program to send IR Signal to my audio player, SendChannelUpCode and SendChannelUpCodeONE is responsible for sending two types of IR signals one for playing a CD and the other for AUX mode, if i open the serial and if i type 1 CD mode it will run but i cant type "2" again and send another signal i must turn off then on the serial then press 2 to run, any suggestions of how to not restart the serial everytime to change between the modes?

I have tried using return on the SendChannelUpCode function and tried putting exit(1) after i call the function but still having the same problem, and i cant use break functions because its in an IF statement error

```
void setup(){
pinMode(IRledPin, OUTPUT);  

Serial.begin(9600);

while (!Serial);

Serial.println("Input 1 to Turn CD on  and 2 to turn AUX mode");

}

void loop() {

if (Serial.available())

{

int state = Serial.parseInt();

if (state == 1)

{


Serial.println("Command completed, CD MODE ON");
delay(100);
SendChannelUpCode();


}

if (state == 2)

{

Serial.println("Command completed, AUX MODE ON");
delay(100);
SendChannelUpCodeONE();


}

}

}


 void pulseIR(long microsecs) {


   cli();  
   while (microsecs > 0) {
    digitalWrite(IRledPin, HIGH); 
    delayMicroseconds(10);   
    digitalWrite(IRledPin, LOW);   
    delayMicroseconds(10);        
    microsecs -= 26;
   }
 }

void SendChannelUpCode() {  


     delayMicroseconds(28136  );      //Time off (LEFT column)
   pulseIR(9280  );

   delayMicroseconds(4600 );
   pulseIR(600  );
 } 


void SendChannelUpCodeONE() {  

       delayMicroseconds(28136  );      //Time off (LEFT column)
   pulseIR(9280  );

   delayMicroseconds(4600 );
   pulseIR(600  );
}
```

Comment: Looks like a candidate for an additional thread.  If the function you are calling has a return type other than `void`, have you tried to look at its return value?  Is it even returning in a reasonable time?  Is it a blocking function?  What is the value of `microsecs` when passed as an argument into the statement: `void pulseIR(long microsecs)`.  (You do not include the call to that function in your example.)  Also, to help those who would like to help you, provide a [mcve].

Comment: the micro seconds and pulseIR are only bunch of hex data that i got from the remote using an IR receiver and it doesn't have any return functions the data looks like that :
``` void SendChannelUpCodeONE() {  


    delayMicroseconds(28136  );      //Time off (LEFT column)
   pulseIR(9280  );

   delayMicroseconds(4600 );
   pulseIR(600  );
   
   delayMicroseconds(560  );
   pulseIR(600  );
   delayMicroseconds(1700  );
   pulseIR(600  );
   ...
} ```

Comment: I updated the code i added a sample of what the SendChannelUpCode looks like check it out.

Comment: I don't know arduino that well, but could it be that serial is interrupt driven? What does the cli() function that you call in pulseIR do?